# Hide <canvas> element

Tags: javascript, canvas

Somewhere in my javascript code, there is a function which injects a canvas element in my code . The canvas element is being displayed for 10 seconds then it disappears.

This is the code that is being injected..

```
<canvas style="position: absolute; bottom: 15px; top: auto; left: 15px; z-index: 100000; visibility: visible; cursor: pointer;" y="0" x="0" height="17" width="46"></canvas>
```

The problem is that i can't find that bit of code in my javascript. Is there another way to hide the  completely?

Comment: Hide it with css? set display to none for canvas element

Comment: @Huangism it will hide all canvases on page

Comment: @EugenHalca yep, OP never mentions any other canvas

Comment: I think you should figure out what is injecting a canvas into your code and get rid of that instead of worrying about hiding it...

Comment: I tried with css display: none !important but it seems that this is ignored

Answer (score 15):

Really?

> i can't find that bit of code in my javascript

Anyway,

Assuming(!) that this is the only canvas at x==0,y==2 sized at width==46,height==17 you can use `document.querySelector` to fetch the canvas and hide it.

```
// build the query selector for the desired canvas
var query="canvas[x='0'][y='0'][height='17'][width='46']";

// find the canvas
var canvas=document.querySelector(query);

// hide the canvas
canvas.style.display="none";
```

If there are more canvases with that position and size, you must use querySelectorAll to get a list of all the matching canvas nodes and then iterate that list to find the canvas with the matching style attributes.

Comment: This is a part of the code: 

`3t(11,H.3u(2a))}12 57(){11.1U.3t(11,H.3u(2a))}12 7I(){11.1U.3t(11,H.3u(2a))}12 5L(i){13 t={1n:"1O"};1c $.1C(bd,12(e,s){13 n=s.1y(i)`

so really :) I will try your suggestion asap

Comment: It can't find any canvas element :/ It says canvas is null.

Comment: This code *will* fetch any canvas with your specified size and position.  If it doesn't then (1) you don't have a canvas as you've described, or (2) the canvas is being injected/reinjected after you're testing.

Answer (score 4):

You can hide canvas use hidden field

```
  let canvasRef = this.canvasRef.current;
  let canvasRect = canvasRef.getBoundingClientRect();
  this.ctx = canvasRef.getContext("2d");
  this.ctx.canvas.hidden = true;
```